# Scaling image causes temporary jitter

Tags: javascript, jquery, css, svg, png

This may be a duplicate question; I wasn't exactly sure how to word it so I wasn't able to find an answer.

I'm using jQuery to make an image pop out when the page loads. See http://jsfiddle.net/KT728/

The issue is that when the image reaches its final size, the edges are jittery/rough for a second or two, after which they become smooth. I've noticed this in Safari and Firefox so far. Here's the code for the animation:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $("img").animate({
        opacity: 1,
        width: "300px",
        height: "300px"
    }, 400, "swing", function() {
        $("img").animate({
            width: "200px",
            height: "200px"
        });
    });
});
```

I'm using PNG images that are 512px by 512px, scaled down anywhere from 10 by 10 to 300 by 300.

Would converting the PNG images to SVG format solve the issue, or at least make it less obvious? Are SVG images supported by most recent browsers?

Comment: Are you sure this isn't an artefact of "progressive scan" and the image being scaled while it's still being loaded?  On my Chrome browser I thought I saw the effect on first load, but not on subsequent loads when the image was already in cache.

Comment: http://caniuse.com/svg

Comment: OK - tried in Safari - I see what you mean - the anti-aliasing doesn't get applied immediately.

Comment: This isn't a fix to your problem, but you should look into using CSS3 transitions for this. They are a lot lighter and smoother for less powerful devices (mobile) than using jQuery. Take a look here for a simple example http://jsfiddle.net/sgMJH/1/